# Remove a matching string after a specific string a file using shell command

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have below content in my file abcd.yml with below indentation:

```
buildConfig:
  env:
    credentials:       # want to remove this from file
      - id: TEST_ID    # want to remove this from file
        user: username # want to remove this from file 
        password: password  # want to remove this from file
scan:
    credentials:
      - id: scan_id
        user: username
        password: password
```

**Tried the below :**

```
sed -i '/credentials:/d'  abcd.yml
sed -i '/- id: TEST_ID/d'  abcd.yml
sed -i '/user: username/d'  abcd.yml
sed -i '/password: password/d'  abcd.yml
```

But it is removing all the occurrence of the above strings  from file which I don't want.

**Expected Output:**

```
buildConfig:
  env:
scan:
    credentials:
      - id: scan_id
        user: username
        password: password
```

I need to do this for 1000 files .Hence a script  is required to do it .The file is in .yml format.

Comment: Have you googled yaml editors? I hear `yq` is available for Unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a yaml parser like [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) for this:

```
$ yq eval 'del(.buildConfig.env.credentials)' abcd.yml > newfile.yml
$ cat newfile.yml

buildConfig:
  env: {}
scan:
  credentials:
    - id: scan_id
      user: username
      password: password
```

tested with version v4.30.8

Comment: Hi @Paolo I am getting invalid text  "del(.buildConfig.env.credentials)'" . is it some thing to do with yq version

Comment: @abhic which `yq` version are you using?

Comment: Hi @Paolo It  is 4.26.1

Comment: @abhic I just tested with `4.26.1` and it worked fine.. did you copy and paste my command as is?

Comment: Hi @Paolo.. No..I typed it

Comment: @abhic right... try just copying and pasting as is

Comment: Hi @Paolo .It worked.The  '  ' needed to be removed for me.Thank you:-)

Comment: Hi @Paolo .I want the content in the same file.It is creating another file with new name.

Comment: @abhic change `newfile.yml` to `abcd.yml` then